# How to do the Logic behind the next button in angularjs wizard

Tags: angularjs

I have a customers.create.html partial bound to the WizardController.

Then I have 3 customers.create1,2,3.html partial files bound to WizardController1,2,3

Each WizardController1,2 or 3 has an isValid() function. This function determines wether the user can proceed to the next step.

The next button at the bottom of the pasted html should be disabed if ALL ? isValid() functions are false...

Thats my question but the same time that seems not correct to me.

I guess I am not doing the Wizard correctly...

Can someone please guide me how I should proceed with the architecture that the bottom next button is disabled when the current step isValid function returns false, please.

How can I make a connection from the WizardController to any of the WizardController1,2 or 3 ?

Is Firing an event like broadcast a good direction?

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-primary':isCurrentStep(0)}" ng-click="setCurrentStep(0)">One</button>
    <button class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-primary':isCurrentStep(1)}" ng-click="setCurrentStep(1)">Two</button>
    <button class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-primary':isCurrentStep(2)}" ng-click="setCurrentStep(2)">Three</button>
</div>

<div ng-switch="getCurrentStep()" ng-animate="'slide'" class="slide-frame">

    <div ng-switch-when="one">
        <div ng-controller="WizardController1" ng-include src="'../views/customers.create1.html'"></div>
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-when="two">
        <div ng-controller="WizardController2" ng-include src="'../views/customers.create2.html'"></div>
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-when="three">
        <div ng-controller="WizardController3" ng-include src="'../views/customers.create3.html'"></div>
    </div>

</div>

<a class="btn" ng-click="handlePrevious()" ng-show="!isFirstStep()">Back</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="" ng-click="handleNext(dismiss)">{{getNextLabel()}}</a>



'use strict';
angular.module('myApp').controller('WizardController', function($scope) {

    $scope.steps = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    $scope.step = 0;
    $scope.wizard = { tacos: 2 };

    $scope.isFirstStep = function() {
        return $scope.step === 0;
    };

    $scope.isLastStep = function() {
        return $scope.step === ($scope.steps.length - 1);
    };

    $scope.isCurrentStep = function(step) {
        return $scope.step === step;
    };

    $scope.setCurrentStep = function(step) {
        $scope.step = step;
    };

    $scope.getCurrentStep = function() {
        return $scope.steps[$scope.step];
    };

    $scope.getNextLabel = function() {
        return ($scope.isLastStep()) ? 'Submit' : 'Next';
    };

    $scope.handlePrevious = function() {
        $scope.step -= ($scope.isFirstStep()) ? 0 : 1;
    };

    $scope.handleNext = function(dismiss) {
        if($scope.isLastStep()) {
            dismiss();
        } else {
            $scope.step += 1;
        }
    };
});
```

durandalJS wizard sample code which could be used to rewrite a wizard for angularJS:

```
define(['durandal/activator', 'viewmodels/step1', 'viewmodels/step2', 'knockout', 'plugins/dialog', 'durandal/app', 'services/dataservice'],
    function (activator, Step1, Step2, ko, dialog, app, service) {

        var ctor = function (viewMode, schoolyearId) {
            debugger;
            if (viewMode === 'edit') {
                service.editSchoolyear(schoolyearId);
            }
            else if (viewMode === 'create') {
                service.createSchoolyear();
            }

            var self = this;
            var steps = [new Step1(), new Step2()];
            var step = ko.observable(0);   // Start with first step
            self.activeStep = activator.create();
            var stepsLength = steps.length;

            this.hasPrevious = ko.computed(function () {
                return step() > 0;
            });

            self.caption = ko.observable();           
            this.activeStep(steps[step()]);

            this.hasNext = ko.computed(function () {
                if ((step() === stepsLength - 1) && self.activeStep().isValid()) {
                    // save
                    self.caption('save');
                    return true;
                } else if ((step() < stepsLength - 1) && self.activeStep().isValid()) {
                    self.caption('next');
                    return true;
                }
            });

            this.isLastStep = function() {
                return step() === stepsLength - 1;
            }

            this.next = function() {
                if (this.isLastStep()) {

                    $.when(service.createTimeTable())
                     .done(function () {
                         app.trigger('savedTimeTable', { isSuccess: true });
                     })
                     .fail(function () {
                         app.trigger('savedTimeTable', { isSuccess: false });
                     });

                }
                else if (step() < stepsLength) {
                    step(step() + 1);
                    self.activeStep(steps[step()]);
                }
            }

            this.previous = function() {
                if (step() > 0) {
                    step(step() - 1);
                    self.activeStep(steps[step()]);
                }
            }
        }        
        return ctor;
    });
```

Comment: ok i didn't understand, you are wondering if you are using it the good way or not. As i see in the documentation it doesn't look the same, you don't use directive or handler look at it https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard

Comment: Why should I use directive or handler... There is no reason. All I need is a good approach and I do not think I need another extra module for it. :-)

Comment: Ok, i'll try to look at it tomorrow, i may need it for a professionnal project

Comment: I have just looked at an old WPF project where I used a good Wizard with MVVM (viewmodel) approach. And I looked at another durandalJS wizard. Both have in common that they use a steps collection which contains the step objects. I have posted above the durandalJS code maybe it helps you, I will try to rewrite the angularjs wizard step handling now...